# Why don't we get notifications for chat room creations based on extended comment discussions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, notifications

Why don't we get a notification for creating a chat room? Whenever we comment for too long about a specific problem with another user, the system prompts us to open/create a chat for it. But, I never do that, because we don't get a notification for that in the top bar when one is created. So, why don't we get a notification when someone has created a chat room to continue those discussions?

Comment: Notified about what exactly? When is a notification missing?

Comment: When in a comment we mention a person, he gets a notification at the top notifications sections like `1`, `2` and etc... But we don't get it for chat

Comment: If you mention somebody in chat, they do get a notification. However, not immediately. It takes 15 minutes, IIRC. EDIT: They should also be in the chatroom, I think.

Comment: @VLAZ I've edited to clarify what OP is asking about. Hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: Yes. 15 mins is a long time. But sometimes we don't eve get it

Comment: Yet it does prevent people being spammed with notifications if they are monitoring chat.

Comment: So, can this feature be added?

Comment: Basically, this feature already exists as an option: you can "follow" the post, which should give you a notification of the "moved to chat" auto-comment. You get a notification for a new or edited chat message when the new message fulfills the [requirements for you receiving a chat ping](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/280412/271271). By default, you don't get notifications of the auto-comment that is left when comments are moved to chat, because only the post author and people following the post qualify for notifications of *all* new post comments.

Comment: Does this also give the notification for the chat? I don't think so

Comment: @Makyen OP's talking about a user creating a chat room in a comment thread, not a mod moving comments to chat (which is what you're talking about, right?)

Comment: @wjandrea IIRC, both mods moving all comments to chat and users moving a discussion to chat will post an auto-comment, which any user who is following the post would get a notification about.

Comment: @Makyen I think OP's saying, when a user gets prompted to move to chat, normally there's only one person they're talking to, so why doesn't the auto-comment include an @-tag to notify the other user? Now that I think about it more though, that might be harder to implement than I first thought.

Comment: @Sambhav.K Any further messages posted in chat would then provide notifications which are based on the rules for chat notifications, per the link I previously provided. If you want pings in chat to be more rapidly converted to inbox notifications, you can check "Quicker notifications" on [your chat preferences page](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/17133283/sambhav-k?tab=prefs#instant-notifications).

Comment: @Mayken Uhmm. That inbox is my stackoverflow notfications right?

Comment: And why 15 mins? Why not immediately?

Comment: @Sambhav.K Yes, chat pings turn into inbox notifications, once the selected period (normal or short) expires. I've assumed the reason for this is that chat is, to a large extent, expected to be quite interactive with messages often happening between users much more rapidly than that. When you have the tab open to a chatroom, if you get a ping in that room, then an alert noise will be immediately played and an indicator will be shown in your chat interface that you have a ping. Such pings only become inbox notifications if you don't act to clear the ping in chat prior to the time expiring.

Comment: UserA @s UserB in a shared comment thread. UserB is notified whether they're following the post or not. UserB @s UserA back; UserA is notified whether they're... etc. UserA starts to @ UserB back, but S.O. suggest to go to chat instead; UserA accepts. S.O. posts a link on UserA's behalf, but it doesn't @ anybody; so UserB is NOT notified. UserA tries to @ UserB in the chat room, but cannot because UserB has not joined yet; so UserB is NOT notified. Unless UserB happens upon the link, only options for UserA are: a) go back and keep commenting; b) abandon the conversation. Is that right? 1/3

Comment: AFAIK, the main goal of the "move conversation to chat" suggestion is to keep the comment section clean; its secondary goal, to make it easier for users to have longer-than-average conversations about a certain question or answer. Assuming my previous comment above was right, this issue is making the suggestion miss those goals. If UserA has to get back to the comment section to @ UserB themself, the main goal is missed; if they don't, but have no other means of @-ing UserB, the conversation dies and the secondary goal is missed. Why has it to be like that? 2/3

Comment: Is it that difficult to have the automated comment ping whoever UserA was replying to when the suggestion script was triggered? If it is, maybe a solution could be to just notify every user in that comment thread about the chat room creation. They may want to join too, or maybe it was a 3-way conversation anyways, who knows. In any case, I agree that there's room for improvement here (pun not intended). 3/3

Comment: Also, the point I actually wanted to make: it doesn't make sense that we notify users of pings in comments even when they are not following the post, but at the same time argue that we cannot notify them about the "chat room for you" comment unless they are following the post ‍♂️ (Sorry, my train of thought got a bit derailed before.)

Comment: @walen Even if the user has never entered the room, an actual reply to an earlier chat message by that user (not just an @ ping) will ping, and generate an inbox notification for the user. Unfortunately, all this does break down when the user has less than the 20 reputation points which are necessary for participating in chat, as they won't be able to post messages to that chat room, unless a moderator has explicitly added them to the write access list for that room. If not in the write access list, I expect they will get the ping (I haven't actually tested), but be unable to reply.

Comment: If what walen et al were suggesting were implemented, it *would* be easy to also take the step of "give explicit write access to users involved in conversation", FWIW. Since we're talking hypotheticals...